# Strange results!!! Is it because of json? or what?

Tags: android, json

I have a class called **GradeModel2** that has 2 members: grade (as string) and sections (as list of strings). I am trying to get my **GradeModel2**s data from a json string that I've read from a server.

```
List<GradeModel2> gradeList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> sectionsList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray grades = jo.getJSONArray("grades");
for (int i=0;i<grades.length();i++){
    sectionsList.clear();
    JSONObject grade = grades.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray sections = grade.getJSONArray("sections");
    Log.e("length",sections.length()+"");
    for (int k=0;k<sections.length();k++)
        sectionsList.add(sections.getString(k));
    gradeList.add(new GradeModel2(grade.getString("grade"), sectionsList));
}
/**************/
for (GradeModel2 grade : gradeList) {
    List<String> ss = grade.getSections();
    for (String s : ss)
        Log.e("section",grade.getGrade()+" : "+s);
}
/**************/
```

The retrieved json string looks like the following:

```
{"id":"596","privileges":"T","grades":[{"grade":"1","sections":["A","B","C"]},{"grade":"3","sections":["A","B"]},{"grade":"7","sections":["A"]},{"grade":"9","sections":["B"]},{"grade":"10","sections":["A"]}]}
```

The problem is that the sections list of all **GradeModel2** objects is of length **1** and value **A** !!!
the first **Log.e**, one line before the inner for loop, shows that the length of the first item of the list is **3** (**A**,**B**, and **C** (see the json)). However, I am trying to print all the sections of each **GradeModel2** object in the inner for loop in the second block, but all I see section **A** for all the grades!!! (see the pic)

[the result of the two Log.e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrL2A.png)

What is going on? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in `sectionsList`. You are trying to reuse same object, so this line of code `new GradeModel2(..., sectionsList);` will just add reference to the same `sectionsList`. And because of `sectionsList.clear();` you see "A" from last json section (`{"grade":"10","sections":["A"]}`) To fix this, you have to create new array each time in your for loop. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < grades.length() ; i++){
    List<String> sectionsList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... your json code here
    gradeList.add(new GradeModel2(grade.getString("grade"), sectionsList));
}
```

Comment: It works.. thanks :)  But why **clear()** didn't do what should it do ??